# Why is it not printing the string?

Tags: arrays, c, string, getchar

I'm trying to use `getchar()` to read each character from the standard input
and arrange it through out the array, and finally printing it. The thing is, it isn't printing the array.

I've tried to use a for loop to print out the individual characters from the
array, but still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Considering the string doesn't exceed the maximum of the array (30).

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()  
{
int i, c;
char s[30];

    while((c=getchar()) != EOF){
        s[i] = c;
        i++;
    }
    
    printf("%s", s);
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for your help.

For those reading this with the same problem, **I solved it by**:

- initializing `i` with `0`;
- initializing `s` with `0` values;
- instead of `EOF`, I used `'\n'`.

Comment: How are you expecting `printf` to know how many characters to print?

Answer (score 2):

You got unlucky and your code didn't instantly crash. Instead you're overwriting memory at random.

The thing you're missing is initializing `i` with `0`. Your code doesn't initialize it and it has whatever is in memory at that location.

> Considering the string doesn't exceed the maximum of the array (30).

You better mean 29, or you're overwriting memory again. Your string has to end with a '\0' character. Speaking of, you should initialize `s` with 0 values as well, or you'll be printing garbage past the end of your string.

Answer (score 0):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define STR_LEN 30
int main() {
    char str[STR_LEN + 1]; // extra space for '\0' c-string delimiter
    int ci = 0; // character index begins at 0 in c-strings
    int ich;    // getchar() returns int that cover EOF
    //you may have to press Ctrl+D in console to input EOF
    //OR more than STR_LEN chars in a single line + ENTER
    while ((ich = getchar()) != EOF && ci < STR_LEN) { // also not reading more than 30 chars
        str[ci] = ich;
        ++ci;
    }
    str[ci] = '\0';  // ending c-string with string delimiter at the end
    printf ("\nRead String: [%s]\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```